# Turn off a particular warning in Flex Builder 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I keep getting this warning:

**warning: unable to bind to property 'image' on class 'XML' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)**

Is there a way I can turn off this type of warning (but keep the others) as it is driving me crazy when I try to trace something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `-show-binding-warnings=false` to the additional compiler arguments area. Here is a list of [mxmlc compiler options](http://flexstuff.googlepages.com/FlexCompilerOptions.html).

Though occasionally helpful (as it makes easier to locate other warnings in a huge bunch of them), hiding these warnings is not always a good idea - sometime later you will find yourself wondering why the heck is that DataGrid not updated when I update it's dataProvier XMLList.

Comment: Do you have any idea, why this might NOT work in FB 4.7 with Flex 4.10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but you are probably looking for a compiler option to mxmlc. These can be set in flex builder for a particular project by right clicking a Project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler -> Additional compiler arguments.